# Plupload Error -200 HTTP Error

Tags: cross-domain, plupload, http-error

I am trying to move the uploading on a remote server. After I choose a file with the code below and click upload the file IS uploaded, but an error returns saying code: "-200" message: "HTTP Error"

```
       var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(
       {
           runtimes : 'html4, html5, flash, silverlight',
           browse_button : 'bt_browse',
           container: document.getElementById('container'),
           url : 'http://remote.com/upload.php',
           silverlight_xap_url : 'js/Moxie.xap',
           chunks_size: '20mb',
           max_retries: 3,
           filters : {
           max_file_size : '100mb'
       },
       multi_selection : true,  
       init: {
         PostInit: function() {
              document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
              document.getElementById('bt_uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                    uploader.start();
                    return false;
              };
         },
         FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                  //build list
    }},
         UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
         $("#progressBar"+file.id).val(Math.round(file.percent));
            if(Math.round(file.percent)==100){
                $("#progressBar"+file.id).hide();
                $("#deleteFile" + file.id).hide();
            }
         },
         FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
            if(file!=undefined) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(info.response);
                if(json.error == undefined)
                  moveFile(json.result, file.name, file.id);
            }
         },
         UploadComplete: function(){
         },
         Error: function(up, err) {
         }
       }
    });
```

What can I do to escape this error and continue? In my case FileUploaded and UploadProgress are not hit at all - after I hit upload I directly moved to Error function. This is really weird for me since after that I check the folder where it is supposed to be and the file is there.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solution. I am also facing the same issue. Some files are uploaded and for some despite the size is with-in the limit, gets `HTTP Error. (-200)`.

Comment: I'm getting this error also. Files below about 3Mb work ok and above don't, even though the max-file-size is set to 6mb

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error when I was using PlUpload in an MVC5 application. The problem was that the REST method could not be found. PlUpload using a multipart for data. The code below shows how this could be implemented in a WebAPI

```
public class UploadFilesController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData() 
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            var TestId = provider.FormData.Get("TestId");
            var chunk = provider.FormData.Get("chunk");
            var chunks = provider.FormData.Get("chunks");
            var fileName = provider.FormData.Get("name");

            int chunkId = Convert.ToInt32(chunk);
            int totalChunks = Convert.ToInt32(chunks);
            Boolean isLastChunch = chunkId == totalChunks - 1;


            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                //Console.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
                string FileDestination = Path.GetDirectoryName(file.LocalFileName) + @"\" + fileName;

                using (FileStream fileUpload = new FileStream(file.LocalFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(FileDestination, chunkId == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.Length];
                        fileUpload.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }
                }
                File.Delete(file.LocalFileName);
            }

            if (isLastChunch) {
                // Do something with the completed file
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }

    }
```